# One or two dialog instances for adding and editing?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

is better to create two dialog instance, one for adding and one for editing, or is it possible to use one dialog?

**Example** This is what I am currently using

```
        // Add Dialog 
        $('#addProgramDialog').dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            width: 400,
            height: 500,
            title: 'Add Program',
            buttons: {
                'Cancel': function () {
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                },
                'Save': function () {
                    saveProgramRequest();
                }
            }
        });


        // Edit Dialog 
        $('#editProgramDialog').dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            width: 400,
            height: 500,
            title: 'Edit Program',
            buttons: {
                'Cancel': function () {
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                },
                'Update': function () {
                    updateProgramRequest();
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: This may be more appropriate for http://www.ux.stackexchange.com. You talk about showing both the dialogs at the same time or displaying a single dialog with more information, don't you?

Comment: DRY would be a nice solution, although I'm not sure if it's possible to create a function / object in which you can add `#addProgramDialog`, `Add Program`, etc. as parameters.. Maybe someone else knows?

Comment: You surely can combine this two functions for DRY coding. Simply create some variables and instead of title: 'Add Program' use title: myVariable , variable which is set before the dialog call with a conditional statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the DRY Principle you should never repeat yourself.  In your example you are duplicating the declaration of the width, height, autoOpen parameter, and Cancel button.  You could prevent this by simply using jQuery's each method to loop over the dialogs and customizing as necessary.  As an example:

```
$('#addProgramDialog, #editProgramDialog').each(function(index, node) {
    var options = {
        //autoOpen: false,
        width: 400,
        height: 500,
        buttons: {
            'Cancel': function() {
                $(this).dialog('close');
            }
        }
    };

    if (node.id == "addProgramDialog") {
        options.title = 'Add Program';
        options.buttons['Save'] = function() {
            saveProgramRequest();
        }
    } else {
        options.title = 'Edit Program';
        options.buttons['Update'] = function() {
            updateProgramRequest();
        }
    }

    $(node).dialog(options);
});
```

Here's a jsFiddle to show this example live - http://jsfiddle.net/YTbnN/.